# How to find a tangent to the curve $y = 12/x + 2$ without using differentiation at all

Tags: analytic-geometry, tangent-line

Please can you explain how to solve this without using differentiation at all.

> The straight line $y = mx + 14$ is a tangent to the curve $y = \frac{12}{x} + 2$ at the point $P$. Find the value of the constant $m$ and the coordinates of $P$.

Comment: You might start by finding the intersections of the line with the curve. What does it mean for the line to be tangent to the curve?

Comment: Try to learn mathjax to write mathematics properly. Is the curve $\;y=\frac{12}x+2\;$ or $\;y=\frac{12}{x+2}\;$? And what have you done so far?

Comment: the former, the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Solve the equation $mx + 14=12/x + 2$. Find the value of $m$ such that the (quadratic) equation has just one solution, that is when  its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_2) is zero. Then the unique solution is the $x$-coordinate of the point of tangency $P$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I did that. Then I get mx^2 + 12x - 12 = 0

Comment: How do I go from there?

Comment: Solve the quadratic equation and consider the discriminant $b^2-4ac=12^2+4\cdot 12\cdot m$! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_2

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $P\left(\dfrac1a,12a+2\right)$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}_{(\text{at }x=1/a)}=-\dfrac{12}{x^2}_{(\text{at }x=1/a)}=-12a^2$$

$$\dfrac{y-(12a+2)}{x-\dfrac1a}=-12a^2\iff12a^2 x+y-24a-2=0$$

This will be identical with $$mx-y+14=0$$

$$\iff\dfrac{12a^2}m=\dfrac1{-1}=-\dfrac{24a+2}{14}$$

Can you take it from here?